# Why is NTFS better than FAT32?

Tags: filesystems, hard-drive, ntfs, fat32

Just wondering why NTFS is considered better, and how NTFS manages to do so (structure, actions, etc), compared to FAT.

thanks! :)

Comment: While I don't think anyone will argue the fact that NTFS is (in the vast majority of cases) a better filesystem than FAT32, debating these points is not the goal of SF. If you have a specific question about either of these, please ask it, otherwise this will likely get closed.

Comment: Sorry. But later Windows versions replaced FAT with NTFS, didn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's an accurate statement.

Comment: There isn't a specific question... as ErikA mentioned.  Is there a specific goal for "Just wondering?"

Comment: upvote, totally lame closure

Comment: @ChrisMarisic, it isn't really a system admin question.  The question is ask in a way that invites debate and arguments.  This is a Q&A site, not a forum.  It would probably have been migrated, and not downvoted if the question had title had been 'What features or functionality does NTFS provide that makes it the preferred default Windows Filesystem?'  When asking a question, it is important to write it in a way that encourages objective answers.  If the title has 'better/best', that is a big red flag.

Comment: "if the question had title had been 'What features or functionality does NTFS provide that makes it the preferred default Windows Filesystem?' " THIS right here proves my assertion is accurate. If the issue was with how it was phrased, improve the question, don't close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- A default larger unit size allocation
- Encrypition (EFS)
- Compression (ZIP)
- A Journal.
- Hard links.
- .....

Comment: IMO, The most important NTFS feature by far, is the access control lists.  On a server it is critical to be able say who has access to what.

Comment: @Zoredache true!